# OpenCV Runtime "Errors" Not Shown

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there a way to configure OpenCV to output runtime "errors" which seem they should be errors but are not reported at all?

For example, I had built OpenCV incorrectly so using some functionality (such as cvwriteframe) would simply not work - no runtime errors or anything, just no functionality. cvWriteFrame could be called with no print/error messages (even though it did not work). This was incredibly difficult and frustrating to trace since there is no console output, no compile error, no linker error, just no functionality.

Is there a way to configure the library when building to give feedback or something when this happens? My specific problem was caused by not properly linking to ffmpeg when I built OpenCV but **nothing** in building or running my app would ever have hinted at this being the root cause.

I am hoping, against hope, there is a way to do this, but nothing I've found indicates OpenCV will give the output I'm looking for though :(

Comment: It seems the newest build of OpenCV (2.4) which was just released might include some of this information - http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a configuration setting within building of OpenCV (in CMake) which is

`OPENCV_WARNINGS_ARE_ERRORS`

This seems to be the only option which is close.